# Periodic Work manager not working when app is killed

Tags: android, background-process, android-workmanager

I am trying to send offline messages to server when app is killed, for this I had impelemented the   periodic work manager but it is not working when app is killed even after 15 minutes.

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001" ;
    private final static String default_notification_channel_id = "default" ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Constraints constraints =new Constraints.Builder()
              .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)// there are some more constraints we can set
              .build();
    Log.d("dsfdsf","dsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdf");
    //create one time request
      Data inputData = new Data.Builder()
              .putString("WORKER", "app")
              .build();

      final PeriodicWorkRequest myWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(WorkService.class,1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
              .setInputData(inputData)
              .setConstraints(constraints)
              .build();
      WorkManager workManager =  WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
      workManager.enqueue(myWorkRequest);

    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum interval for PeriodicWork is 15 minutes. Can you please change the interval to 15 and check?